# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, websocket

I want to try to create some sort of a bot for an android game and it gives me this Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 505, in <module>
    a.login_and_collect()
  File "main.py", line 375, in login_and_collect
    self.req_sdk_login(svr_id)
  File "main.py", line 86, in req_sdk_login
    res= self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())
  File "main.py", line 355, in callAPI
    if not hasattr(self,'ws'):  self.getWS()
  File "main.py", line 33, in getWS
    self.ws = create_connection("ws://hgame-tva-slb-gs.lilithgame.com:10000", header={'Upgrade':'websocket','Connection':'Upgrade','Sec-WebSocket-Key':self.getRND(),'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol':'game_10001','Sec-WebSocket-Version':'13'})
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 514, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 226, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 73, in handshake
    headers, key = _get_handshake_headers(resource, hostname, port, options)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 138, in _get_handshake_headers
    for k, v in header.items()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 139, in <listcomp>
    if v is not None
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found
```

I already searched for this error on google and found some answers, but none of them work. Why am I getting this error?

Initially I created this script in Python 2.x
but now I have Python 3.7 it doesn't work. I already used 2to3, but it still gives me the error since I am not very known with py3.7

Could someone help me? or correct the code please?
Help is very much appreciated

Initially I created this script in Python 2.x
but now I have Python 3.7 it doesn't work. I already used 2to3 and converted some on my own, but it still gives me the error since I am not very known with py3.7

```
def getWS(self):
   if hasattr(self, 'ws'):
      self.ws.close()           
   self.ws = create_connection("ws://hgame-tva-slb-gs.lilithgame.com:10000", header={'Upgrade':'websocket','Connection':'Upgrade','Sec-WebSocket-Key':self.getRND(),'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol':'game_10001','Sec-WebSocket-Version':'13'})
```

It should get some data from the "ws://" connection but the result is still a byte instead of a string...

How do I solve the problem?

Edit (This is the complete script where the error comes from):

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
from websocket import create_connection
import common_pb2
import down_pb2
import time
import base64
import os
import up_pb2
import websocket
import inspect
import sys
from lilithgame import lilithgame
from db import Database

class API(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.cli_version="1.17"
    self.up_pb2=up_pb2
    self.down_pb2=down_pb2
    self.common_pb2=common_pb2
    self.seq=100
    self.lilithgame=lilithgame()
    self.db=Database()
    self.cmd=True

def getRND(self):
    return base64.b64encode(os.urandom(16))

def getWS(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'ws'):
        self.ws.close()         
    self.ws = create_connection("ws://hgame-tva-slb-gs.lilithgame.com:10000", header={'Upgrade':'websocket','Connection':'Upgrade','Sec-WebSocket-Key':self.getRND(),'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol':'game_10001','Sec-WebSocket-Version':'13'})

def setCollectRewards(self):
    self.canrewards=True

def setcmd(self):
    self.cmd=False

def setOpenId(self, id):
    self.open_id=str(id)

def setToken(self, token):
    self.token=token

def setDevice(self, device):
    self.device=self.common_pb2.ios if device=='ios' else self.common_pb2.android
    self.log('[!] our OS is:%s'%(device))

def log(self, msg):
    if hasattr(self, 'cmd') and self.cmd==False:    return
    print(('[%s] %s'%(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), msg.encode('utf-8'))))

def makeplain(self, i):
    return self.up_pb2.up_msg().FromString(i.decode('hex'))

def getplainresponse(self, i):
    return self.down_pb2.down_msg().FromString(i)

def login(self, platform, open_id, svr_id, uid, htoken):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_reconnect.platform = self.common_pb2.lilith
    msg.req_reconnect.open_id = open_id
    msg.req_reconnect.svr_id = svr_id
    msg.req_reconnect.uid = uid
    msg.req_reconnect.htoken = htoken
    msg.req_reconnect.cli_version = self.cli_version
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_sdk_login(self,svr_id=False,is_debug=False):
    if not hasattr(self, 'open_id'):
        self.log('[-] open_id missing...')
        exit(1)
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=1
    msg.req_sdk_login.platform = self.common_pb2.lilith
    msg.req_sdk_login.open_id = self.open_id
    msg.req_sdk_login.token = self.token
    msg.req_sdk_login.is_debug = is_debug
    msg.sign = 'e600502f76fe5dbf539687e23295560b'
    if svr_id:  msg.req_sdk_login.svr_id = svr_id
    res= self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())
    self.htoken=res.reply_sdk_login.htoken
    self.svr_id=res.reply_sdk_login.svr_id
    self.log('[!] using server %s'%(self.svr_id))
    if False:   self.log('htoken:%s svr_id:%s'%(self.htoken, self.svr_id))
    return res

def req_heartbeat(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_heartbeat.hb_cnt = 0
    msg.req_heartbeat.hb_delay = 0
    msg.req_heartbeat.timeout_cnt = 0
    msg.req_heartbeat.timeout_length = 15000
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_tutorial(self, ids):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    for id in ids:
        msg.req_tutorial.new_tutorials.append(id)
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def query_assist_summaries(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.query_assist_summaries.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def get_acc_users(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_acc.get_acc_users.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def update_rating(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_rating.update_rating.status=self.common_pb2.have_rated
    msg.req_rating.update_rating.add_count=0
    msg.req_rating.update_rating.action=self.common_pb2.second_day_reward
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def next_chapter(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.next_chapter.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_open_panel(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.req_open_panel.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_daily_login(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_daily_login.recv_reward=1
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def recv_reward(self, challenge_id, task_id):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_challenge.recv_reward.challenge_id=challenge_id
    msg.req_challenge.recv_reward.task_id=task_id
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_red_dot(self, _type, id):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_red_dot.rm.type=_type
    msg.req_red_dot.rm.id=id
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_tavern_draw(self, tavern_id):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_tavern.req_tavern_draw.tavern_id=tavern_id
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_recv_todo_reward(self, req_recv_todo_reward):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_task.req_recv_todo_reward=req_recv_todo_reward
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_recv_chest(self, req_recv_chest):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_task.req_recv_chest=req_recv_chest
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_recv_line_reward(self, req_recv_line_reward):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_task.req_recv_line_reward=req_recv_line_reward
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def query_reward(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.query_reward.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def draw_rewards(self):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.draw_rewards.Clear()
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_up_level(self, hero_id, up_level):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_unit.req_up_level.hero_id=hero_id
    msg.req_unit.req_up_level.up_level=up_level
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def req_wear_best_equip(self, req_wear_best_equip):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_unit.req_wear_best_equip=req_wear_best_equip
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def start_battle(self, stage_id):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.start_battle.stage_id=stage_id
    idx=0
    self.heroes.reverse()
    for h in self.heroes:
        if idx>4:   break
        if False:   self.log('slot:%s hero_id:%s'%(idx, h))
        new_lineup = msg.req_stage.start_battle.lineup.add()
        new_lineup.slot=idx+1
        new_lineup.hero_id=h
        idx+=1
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString(), True)

def end_battle(self, battle):
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_stage.end_battle.result = self.common_pb2.victory
    rounds=msg.req_stage.end_battle.rounds.add()
    rounds.round = 1
    rounds.result = self.common_pb2.victory
    rounds.self_team.slot_heroes.MergeFrom(battle.reply_stage.start_battle.start_battle_info.input.self_teams[0].slot_heroes)
    rounds.oppo_team.Clear()
    rp=common_pb2.round_op()
    map1={}
    map1[255]=common_pb2.battle_ops()
    map1[255].ops.append(0)
    rp.operations.MergeFrom(map1)
    rounds.round_op.MergeFrom(rp)
    smap1={}
    for i in self.heroes:
        smap1[i]=common_pb2.hero_stat()
        smap1[i].hp_pct=10000
        smap1[i].mp_pct=10000
        smap1[i].param=0
        smap1[i].damage=10000
        smap1[i].kill=0
        smap1[i].heal=0
        smap1[i].defend=0
    rounds.self_stats.MergeFrom(smap1)
    pmap1={}
    pmap1[1]=common_pb2.hero_stat()
    pmap1[1].hp_pct=0
    pmap1[1].mp_pct=1061
    pmap1[1].param=0
    pmap1[1].damage=99
    pmap1[1].kill=0
    pmap1[1].heal=0
    pmap1[1].defend=332
    rounds.oppo_stats.MergeFrom(pmap1)
    msg.req_stage.end_battle.cli_ver='cli:afkarena_v1.16.04.44921;bcv:2.0'
    msg.req_stage.end_battle.param=37283
    return self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())

def showtasks(self, tasks):
    for i in tasks.daily_todolists._values:
        if i.target_progress>=1 and not hasattr(i, 'last_reward_time'):
            self.req_recv_todo_reward(i.id)
    for i in tasks.weekly_todolists._values:
        if i.target_progress>=1 and not hasattr(i, 'last_reward_time'):
            self.req_recv_todo_reward(i.id)
    for i in tasks.line_tasklists._values:
        if i.target_progress>=1 and not hasattr(i, 'last_reward_time'):
            self.req_recv_line_reward(i.line)

def showchallanges(self, challanges):
    for i in challanges._values:
        if hasattr(i, 'tasks'):
            for j in i.tasks._values:
                if j.progress>=1:
                    self.recv_reward(j.challenge_id, j.task_id)

def showunits(self, heroes):
    self.log('[!] have %s units'%(len(heroes)))
    self.heroes=[]
    used=set()
    isAllLvl1=True
    for i in heroes:
        if i.level!=1:
            isAllLvl1=False
            break
    for i in heroes:
        if i.tid in used:   continue
        if not isAllLvl1 and i.level==1:    continue
        #if i.level<50: continue
        self.log('id:%s rank:%s level:%s quality:%s'%(i.id, i.rank, i.level, i.quality))
        self.heroes.append(i.id)
        used.add(i.tid)

def req_login(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'device'):
        self.device=self.common_pb2.ios
    msg=self.up_pb2.up_msg()
    msg.seq=self.seq
    msg.repeat=0
    msg.req_login.platform=self.common_pb2.lilith
    msg.req_login.os=self.device
    msg.req_login.open_id=self.open_id
    msg.req_login.svr_id=self.svr_id
    msg.req_login.htoken=self.htoken
    msg.req_login.cli_version=self.cli_version
    msg.req_login.time_zone=2
    msg.req_login.lang=self.common_pb2.en
    msg.req_login.push_id="jpush-191e35f7e00af97c8e4"
    msg.req_login.idfa="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    msg.req_login.google_aid=""
    msg.req_login.android_id=""
    msg.req_login.os_version="10.2"
    msg.req_login.app_version="1.16.03"
    msg.req_login.device="iPad5,4"
    msg.req_login.channel_id="self-lilith-0.7"
    msg.req_login.package="com.lilithgame.hgames.ios"
    msg.req_login.name="New Player"
    res= self.callAPI(msg.SerializeToString())
    self.user=res.reply_login.user_info
    self.cur_stage=res.reply_login.user_info.stage.cur_stage
    if False:   self.log('[!] cur_stage:%s'%(self.cur_stage))
    self.showunits(res.reply_login.user_info.heroes._values)
    if hasattr(self, 'canrewards'): self.showtasks(res.reply_login.user_info.task_info)
    if hasattr(self, 'canrewards'): self.showchallanges(res.reply_login.user_info.challenges)
    self.log('uid:%s level:%s gold:%s diamonds:%s'%(res.reply_login.user_info.uid, res.reply_login.user_info.level, res.reply_login.user_info.gold, res.reply_login.user_info.rmb))
    return res

def callAPI(self,data,needSecond=False):
    if not hasattr(self,'ws'):  self.getWS()
    self.ws.send_binary(data)
    result = self.ws.recv()
    self.seq+=1
    res= self.getplainresponse(result)
    if 'err_stage_battle_gs_limit' in text_format.MessageToString(res):
        self.log('[!] Your team isnt\'t strong enough yet!')
        return None
    if needSecond:
        try:
            while(inspect.stack()[1][3] not in text_format.MessageToString(res)):
                result = self.ws.recv()
                res= self.getplainresponse(result)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit(1)
    if True:    self.log('%s(): %s'%(inspect.stack()[1][3], res.reply_seq))
    return res
    #self.ws.close()

def login_and_collect(self,svr_id=False):
    self.req_sdk_login(svr_id)
    self.req_login()
    self.query_assist_summaries()
    self.req_heartbeat()
    self.query_reward()
    self.draw_rewards()

def questuntil(self, max):
    if not hasattr(self, 'cur_stage'):
        self.log('..missing..')
        exit(1)
    done=0
    while(done<max):
        self.doquest(self.cur_stage+done)
        done+=1

def doquest(self, stage_id):
    self.log('[!] finishing quest:%s'%(stage_id))
    battle=self.start_battle(stage_id)
    if not battle:
        self.log('[!] do not have battle data..')
        return
    self.req_heartbeat()
    return self.end_battle(battle)

def addAccountToDb(self):
    return self.db.addAccount(self.user.uid, self.user.level, self.user.gold, self.user.rmb, self.token, self.open_id)

def updateAccount(self):
    return self.db.updateAccount(self.user.level, self.user.gold, self.user.rmb, self.open_id)

def showallaccounts(self):
    res=self.get_acc_users()
    #for i in res.reply_acc.user_summaries._values:
    #   print i.uid

def reroll(self,isNew=False):
    if not isNew:
        lilith=self.lilithgame.makeaccount()
        app_token=lilith['app_token']
        app_uid=lilith['app_uid']
        if False:   self.log('app_token:%s app_uid:%s'%(app_token, app_uid))
        self.setOpenId(str(app_uid))
        self.setToken(app_token)
        self.req_sdk_login()
        self.req_login()
    #fishy?
    self.log('[!] doing reroll..')
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    self.doquest(1)
    self.doquest(2)
    self.doquest(3)
    self.doquest(4)
    self.doquest(5)
    self.doquest(6)
    self.doquest(7)
    self.doquest(8)
    self.doquest(9)
    self.doquest(10)
    self.doquest(11)
    self.doquest(12)
    return
    #orig
    self.req_tutorial([1])
    self.query_assist_summaries()
    self.doquest(1)
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2])
    self.doquest(2)
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3])
    self.doquest(3)
    self.req_up_level(1003, 1)
    self.req_wear_best_equip(1003)
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3, 4])
    self.doquest(4)
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    self.doquest(5)
    self.doquest(6)
    self.req_up_level(1003, 1)
    self.req_up_level(1001, 5)
    self.req_up_level(1002, 5)
    self.req_up_level(1000, 5)
    self.doquest(7)
    self.doquest(8)
    self.req_up_level(1003, 5)
    #self.doquest(9)
    self.req_up_level(1001, 5)
    self.req_wear_best_equip(1001)
    self.req_wear_best_equip(1003)
    self.req_wear_best_equip(1002)
    self.req_wear_best_equip(1000)
    self.doquest(10)
    self.doquest(11)
    self.doquest(12)
    self.next_chapter()
    self.query_assist_summaries()
    self.req_open_panel()
    self.req_tutorial([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    self.req_tavern_draw(1)
    self.req_open_panel()
    self.req_daily_login()
    self.req_red_dot(self.common_pb2.activity, 7)
    self.req_red_dot(self.common_pb2.activity, 7)
    self.recv_reward(3, 21)
    self.req_open_panel()
    self.req_recv_todo_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_todo_reward(4)
    self.req_recv_todo_reward(6)
    self.req_recv_chest(1)
    self.req_recv_chest(2)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(2)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(3)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(2)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(1)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(17)
    self.req_recv_line_reward(5)
    self.req_open_panel()
    self.req_tavern_draw(1)
    self.req_tavern_draw(1)
    self.req_tavern_draw(1)
    self.req_tavern_draw(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
a=API()
a.setOpenId('3414156')
a.setToken('QShls0NoQPFe2fLOkzf86PZxwCWBuF2k')
a.login_and_collect()
```

Comment: in error message I see `for k, v in header.items()` so maybe one of your header is not string. What type of value you get with `self.getRND()` in header `'Sec-WebSocket-Key':self.getRND()` ? Is it string or bytes?

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing more of the code. But usually, this error means you loaded something from disk in binary mode, and didn't converted it to string. So  you need to do `x.decode()` to convert from `bytes` to `string`

Comment: I added the complete script into the post in the bottom.
If someone could take a look at it and maybe give me the solution?

I tried and tried, but cant seem to solve this issue.